# Add link to INBOX: either link reponse tab from current community or global inbox from network profile

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, global-inbox

Top bar menus: Achievements and Review Queues have useful links in top within them; e.g clicking on Achievements menu, you'll find links to privileges and badge, link to all review queues from respective menu in similar way.

[image]

**But I found that Inbox menu doesn't have any link:**

[image]

How about adding link to global inbox `https://stackexchange.com/users/<id>?tab=inbox` or community response tab `https://<site>.stackexchange.com/users/<id>?tab=responses`? I think adding link to **global inbox** would be perfect.

Comment: The link to the global inbox is already there, but hidden; right click the inbox logo and choose 'Open in new tab'.

Comment: There *used* to be a clear link to the global inbox at the bottom of the list of notifications, but it was removed at some point.

Comment: When I look now there *is* an "all items" link in the inbox menu that goes to `https://stackexchange.com/users/<id>?tab=inbox`

Comment: As pointed out by jonrsharpe this seems to already exist https://imgur.com/THvwA8W It is strange some see it but others don't. Could this be some kind of UI bug? You can see from my screenshot the link is there.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog That link after the notifications list is still there for me.

Comment: @MarkKirby I think that is not available for mobile web-app.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto You are right the links are not there on the mobile site, for the inbox or the achievements, but the screenshots in this post clearly shows the desktop site.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto on the mobile version it's at the end of the inbox list - "see all inbox items".

Comment: @jonrsharpe Right!

Comment: Is this effectively asking for the same thing as [Add link to all items in global inbox on chat servers and stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375454/335251) (old UI) or [Add link to full inbox to inbox dialog on stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386158/335251) (new UI)? Or was it already [status-completed] (or no longer reproducible), given the link within the inbox on SE sites that pointed to the inbox tab of the network profile.

Comment: Posted 3 years ago. At present there is a link "Go to full inbox" at the bottom. So, you may trace when that the feature is added may be [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/260388) and tag:status-completed. Thanks