# Add link to all items in global inbox on chat servers and stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, chat, stackexchange.com, global-inbox

On Q&A sites (including metas), the inbox dialog has a link to [all items](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox):

[image]

On the chat servers and on https://stackexchange.com, the link is missing:

[image]

Could it be added?

<sub>FWIW, it's also missing on Area 51, but I guess that won't get any love except for critical security updates until it is migrated to a newer version of the SE software.</sub>

Comment: Should this be closed as no longer reproducible/closed as a duplicate of your more recent request [Add link to full inbox to inbox dialog on stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386158/335251), given that the UI for the inbox has slightly changed?

Comment: @V2Blast heh - that's only a year ago but I forgot about it, I guess ...

Comment: Haha, I was recently looking through inbox-related feature requests, and spotted both of these posts by you – I found it amusing that they were so similar :)

Comment: Usually I do a thorough search when posting a new FR or bug ... maybe this time I relied too much on my memory, especially given the recent changes to the inbox?