# Add link to full inbox to inbox dialog on stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, global-inbox

The [new inbox dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/295232) has a link to your [full inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox) on all sites:

[image]

but not on stackexchange.com:

[image]

It shouldn't be that hard to add it - it can be a static link due to the support for the `/current` user.

Comment: As a workaround, note that the inbox icon itself (both on SE sites and on stackexchange.com itself) is a link to the inbox tab of your network profile.